# Creating a file with specific content and at specific path

Tags: bash, loops, sed, cat

I have a list of directory locations(Mylist) where I have to create a specific file (Myfile) with customized content for each location. 
I am trying to use following routine

```
cat Mylist | while read i; 
do cat Myfile >> "$i";
sed -i 's/root/new/g' "$i"; done
```

It works well and creates Myfile at desired locations. I am then using sed to update the content of this file but I want to use replacement content from another file(User) which are tied to that location, any recommendation/solution.

Example

Mylist

```
c:/drive/service1/
d:/drive/service2/ 
d:/drive/servicex/
```

Myfile

```
This is generic content. Only user "root" can update it
```

What I like for each location is to have Myfile reads

```
Only user "abc" can update it
Only user "xyz" can update it
only user "zzz" can update it
```

`abc`, `xyz` and `zzz` are tied to each location and are stored in separate file . or it can be merged if needed

Comment: Please do wrap your samples in CODE TAGS.

Comment: Please prepend your file contents and code with 4 spaces.  ` I want to use replacement content from another file(User) which are tied to that location` - please clarify. So file or user. What does it mean when user is tied? or when file is tied? `are stored in separate file` - then are they "tied" to location or stored in separate file?

Comment: Why does the data in `Mylist` end with `/`? Are they filenames or directory names?

Comment: It's directory name in mylist .

Comment: @KamilCuk, users are in a separate file. You can think of directory-user pair where directory is in a Myfile and user list is maintained in a separate file. does it help?

Comment: @DanialDanial How could the script tell which user goes with which directory? Also, you use the `>>` redirect to write to the output file; do you really want to *append* to any existing file? If so, do you really want the `sed` command to modify the old content, or just the new?

Comment: @Danial, How is it decided one-to-one correspondence for directory-user list? i.e., mapping of respective directory to user with different files? Is it like number of contents is equal on both files? for e.g., `c:/drive/service1/` corresponds to `xxx` user and so on...

Comment: `user list is maintained in a separate file` then please show example of the user list. How to connect specific line from Mylist to specific user?

Comment: @sungtm,that is correct , there is 1:1 mapping.                             
c:/drive/service1/   user : abc 
d:/drive/service2/   user :xyx
d:/drive/servicex/    user: zzz

Comment: @KamilCuk , Mylist has all possible paths and Users are in another file say Myusers. Both files have same number of records,

Comment: I don't know the format of Myusers file, but I think you want to just [`join`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/join) the files with `-o2.2` option and just `xargs printf 'Only user "%s" can update it\n'` Please show the `Myusers` file. What is it's format? How are columns and rows serparated?

Comment: Both files are text files. Myuser file has 3 lines user1, user2, user 3. What I am trying to do is to reading path from Mylist and then cat >> Myfile and then replacing word root. Is it possible to replace root with user1 , user2 , user3 as I write file to those paths.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel "sed 's#.*#/Only user/s/root/&/#' {}/myName | sed -i -f - {}/myFile" :::: myList
```

This updates all myFile in myList using the name from the myName file in the same directory as the myFile.